# How to undestand a differential equation with $c_0$ values?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $c_0$ be a space of real numbers sequences convergent to $0$ with the supremum norm. Consider the following differential equation
$$x'(t)=f(x(t)), \,\,\,x(0)=0,$$
where $f\colon c_{0}\to c_{0}$ is continuous and $f(x)=y$. Can we understand this  equation as the system of infinetely many differential equations (a sequence of differential equations)
$$x'_n(t)=y_{n}(t),\quad x_{n}(0)=0$$
for all $n\in \mathbb{N}?$ How to justify that?

Comment: Let $y_n(t) = f_n(x(t)).$

Comment: yes, that's exactly what I mean

Comment: Just identifty $x'(t) = (x_n'(t)).$

Comment: But is the existance of Frechet derivative of $x$ from $c_0$ equivalent with the existance of the derivatives for $x_n$?

Comment: Do you know that $\mathscr{L}(\mathbf{R}; \mathrm{E})$ and $\mathrm{E}$ are canonically isomorphic (the first space being that of linear functions from $\mathbf{R}$ into $\mathrm{E}$)?